# Storing data within R function

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I'm writing a function in R that plots some data submitted by the user. The plot area has some polygons defined by a data frame that is constant, does not depend on the submitted data. The dataframe is read from a csv file that has 26 rows and 13 columns.

To make the R file as portable as possible I decided to keep the data frame within the file. As there are quite a lot columns, I come up with the following idea:

```
csv_data <- c(
"h1,h2,h3
v11,v21,v31
v12,v22,v32
v13,v23,v33"
)
write(csv_data, file="temp.csv")
df <- read.csv("temp.csv",header=T)
```

OK, I know this is kind of disgusting. but I don't want to reorganize the original csv to make the data frame in the conventional way, as the dataset is quite big:

```
h1 <- c(v11, v12, v13)
h2 <- c(v21, v22, v23)
h3 <- c(v31, v32, v33)
df <- data.frame(h1,h2,h3)
```

So, is there any more appropriate way to achieve this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to make a data.frame from an array of character variables, how about

```
df<-read.csv(text=csv_data, header=T)
```

At least that way you don't need the write.table.

Comment: But even then, the data will be in memory in two different forms. Actually if you do it once, R can generate the code for the data.frame that you can put in a text file with `dump(c("df"), "")`. Just copy/paste that output to your script file.

Comment: `dput(df)` will do it. `dump` is more when you have multiple objects to write out I believe.

Comment: Excellent ideas! Exactly what I wanted. I'll check the dput and dump as well. I just did not know what to think of.

Comment: @thelatemail true, `dump()` is best for multiple objects, but it also adds the `df<-` part whereas `dput()` leaves the variable off. I just think `dump()` is "more complete."